# postgresql Cross Tab syntax error: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error, crosstab

I am trying to create a cross tab, but it is giving me an error: `No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Here is my query for creating a cross tab:

```
CREATE TABLE regions_ct(region_id SERIAL, region VARCHAR (255));
INSERT INTO regions_ct(region_id, region) VALUES(1,'Asia');
INSERT INTO regions_ct(region_id, region) VALUES(2,'Australia and Oceania');
INSERT INTO regions_ct(region_id, region) VALUES(3,'Central America and the Caribbean');
INSERT INTO regions_ct(region_id, region) VALUES(4,'North America');
INSERT INTO regions_ct(region_id, region) VALUES(5,'Sub-Saharan Africa');
INSERT INTO regions_ct(region_id, region) VALUES(6,'Middle East and North Africa');
INSERT INTO regions_ct(region_id, region) VALUES(7,'Europe');

SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  'select region_id, region
   from regions_ct'
   )
AS regions_ct(region_id SERIAL, region VARCHAR (255));
```

Comment: `serial` isn't a real datatype, use `integer` instead in the table alias.

Answer (score 3):

First, you seem to have not installed the `tablefunc` extension.  Make sure your `-contrib` package is installed (i.e., `yum install postgresql12-contrib`), and then install the `tablefunc` extension so that `crosstab` is available: `CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc`.

Next, it seems that your table definition doesn't lend itself to pivoting.  `crosstab` requires at least 3 columns of which you can collate into a `rowid`, `category`, and `value(s)`.  One way to deal with this is by adding an imaginary category (the second `region_id`):

```
db=# SELECT *
       FROM crosstab( 'select region, region_id, region_id from regions_ct' )
         AS regions_ct( region varchar(255), category1 int );
              region               | category1 
-----------------------------------+-----------
 Asia                              |         1
 Australia and Oceania             |         2
 Central America and the Caribbean |         3
 North America                     |         4
 Sub-Saharan Africa                |         5
 Middle East and North Africa      |         6
 Europe                            |         7
(7 rows)
```

I'm not sure what kind of output you're looking for, but I can try to help if you update your question with your expected output.

Comment: Hi thank you for the advice! I tried your code, however, it tells me `ERROR: syntax error at or near "select" in line 3`. Did you not get this error as well?